# How can i import this Dll

Tags: api, dllimport

I have a "CLock.dll" have some  functions
For example: This is document for a function

```
__int16 __stdcall dv_get_auth_code(unsigned char* auth);
```

Function
To gain authorization code of setup card.
Parameters
auth:[out] Return authorization code, 6 characters.
Return
Succeed then return 0.

I need to call this dll in my winform application. I try

```
[DllImport("CLock.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int dv_get_auth_code([Out]StringBuilder auth);`
```

and in Main()

My code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int result = dv_get_auth_code(sb);
```

But it's working. What should i do? Thank you and have a nice day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes in the code as presented. The return type is wrong, and no buffer is allocated.

The return type is a 16 bit type, in C# that is `short`:

```
[DllImport("Clock.dll")]
public static extern short dv_get_auth_code(StringBuilder auth);
```

Then to call the function you need to allocate a buffer. I don't know how large that buffer should be, presumably you know that.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bufferLengtg);
short result = dv_get_auth_code(sb);
```

It is always wise for such an API to pass the length of the buffer to the function. Then it can make sure it does not overrun the buffer.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is so useful for me. But the result always return -2.
Can i ask you more information for this solution. I need code a API to connect a program to a Lock for a Hotel Management System. This is 1st time i code an API so everything is hard.

Comment: The answer here is correct given the question. The return value is determined by code we can't see